# listview, datapager, objectdatasource not working in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, objectdatasource, datapager

When i change the page in datapager it causes full postback, even the datapager is working very abnormally, idont know what is the reason. by abnormaaly i mean sometime data is shown sometime doesnt,
Following is th my code in c#

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindListView();
        }           
    }

    protected void StudentListView_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        BindListView();
    }
    private void BindListView()
    {
        StudentListView.DataSource = StudentDataSource;
        StudentListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void StudentDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Arguments.MaximumRows = StudentListDataPager.MaximumRows;
        e.Arguments.StartRowIndex = StudentListDataPager.StartRowIndex;
    }
```

Following is my markup

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>        <
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="BatchDropDownList" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Batch 1" Value="1" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Batch 2" Value="2" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:ListView ID="StudentListView" runat="server"       
        ItemPlaceholderID="ListViewContent" 
            EnableViewState="false" 
            onpagepropertieschanging="StudentListView_PagePropertiesChanging"> 
        <LayoutTemplate> 
            <table style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="align-left"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                        <th class="align-left"><strong>MobNo</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody runat="server" id="ListViewContent"> 
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>  
        <ItemTemplate>  

            <tr>
                <td style="width:70%;"><%# Eval("FirstName") %>&nbsp<%# Eval("LastName") %></td>
                <td style="width:30%;"><%# Eval("MobNo") %></td>                    
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>             
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:DataPager ID="StudentListDataPager" runat="server" PageSize="5" PagedControlID="StudentListView">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>


    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="StudentDataSource" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetStudentListBatchWise" SelectCountMethod="StudentCount" 
            TypeName="SCERPCommonUtil.Student" EnablePaging="True" 
            onselecting="StudentDataSource_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="batchId" ControlID="BatchDropDownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please tell me if i am making any mistakes.

P.S. : Please dont point me to any stackoverflow question as i have read all of them, and none is specific to my requirement,

Most important problem i am facing is that datapager is giving full postback, even if put `datapager` inside `updatepanel` same thing happens.

Comment: Dear you have specified updatemode to conditional. Do you have mentioned postback trigger to your update panel ????

Comment: Ok - with `StudentListDataPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);` in `StudentListView_PagePropertiesChanging()` event, the datapager now works fine, but still the problem of update panel stands as daemon, which causes full postback, and i lose all my javascript local variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it - incase somebody come looking -

i was using `<form runat="server">...<form>` tag, inside which all this listview,datapager code was present. When i assigned unique `id` attribute to form tag then everything started working correctly.
Although i dont understand the reason of such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you have specified updatemode to conditional.But you have mentioned any trigger to your update panel.
Add the AsyncPostBackTrigger to your update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="StudentListView" EventName="PagePropertiesChanging" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**From MSDN:**
`If the UpdateMode property is set to Conditional, and one of the following conditions occurs:`

1. You call the Update method of the UpdatePanel control explicitly.
2. The postback is caused by a control that is defined as a trigger by using the Triggers property of the UpdatePanel control. In this scenario, the control explicitly triggers an update of the panel content. The control can be either inside or outside the UpdatePanel control that defines the trigger.
3. The ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true and a child control of the UpdatePanel control causes a postback. A child control of a nested UpdatePanel control does not cause an update to the outer UpdatePanel control unless it is explicitly defined as a trigger.

**Updated Answer:**
why you have not mention DataSourceID attribute in your listview ???

```
 <asp:ListView ID="StudentListView" runat="server"  DataSourceID  ="StudentDataSource"
```

and you are binding your list view in your code behind as

```
private void BindListView()
{
    StudentListView.DataSource = StudentDataSource; //also it should be DataSourceID 
    StudentListView.DataBind();
}
```

you are using object data source and in your code you are binding it as a datasource which is wrong. Bind it as a datasource ID or simple mention the datasourceID attribute of listview then you don't have to bind it in your code behind.

Comment: `PagePropertiesChanging` event is associated with ListView and not with DataPager, also i have removed UpdateMode and tried but its still not working..

Comment: sorry I give wrong ID to trigger. Your code works normal without update panel ???? Check it

Comment: sorry,  but what you suggest is not working it is still giving full postback.

Comment: of course it will work normal without updatepanel, but i want to use update panel for ajax functionality.

Comment: both the approcah are correct - setting DataSourceId in markup or setting DataSource in code behind, but datapager is causing full postback, that is why i tried the apprach of code behind ( as read about it in some article )

Comment: @j4m4l There is a difference between DataSourceID and DataSource. DatasourceID's are data source controls like sqldatasource,linqds,objds etc where as in datasource you can also specify datatable object.

Comment: thnx for that trigger thing, that was my mistake, but my problem is still not solved, that datapager is causing full postback. Where it should not as ListView is inside update panel

Comment: see this link they are not using any event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx i will be back after an hour...

Comment: Ok as i told i read in some article that setting `DataSource` will not cause full postback, i have tried setting `DataSourceID` also but still i have full postback

Comment: @j4m4l it looks like your update panel is not working. Remove everything from it just place a button control and a label control to check it causes a complete postback or not. Or the problem occurs only when you use listview with pager.

Comment: yes updatepanel is working, one more thing there is a function in page inserted by asp.net `function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {....}` this function gets called when there is postback. With my new button this is not called, but with datapager it is called. So i should assume that datapager gives a postback by design

Comment: @j4m4l yes datapager causes a  post back.

Comment: @Waqar_Janjua so finally does that mean i cant use datapager inside updatepanel, as i will lose all my javascript variable values.

Comment: @j4m4l no you can use. Sorry but I can't understand why update panel is not working. ( why a full post back occurs. )